# Recipient auto-assignment in email sent from flow

Tags: email, visual-workflow

More than anything, my question is to know if there is any official documentation regarding the following case:

- I have an autolaunched flow that sends emails to a list of users every time a record is updated (called from another flow).
- Sending is done through Apex Action "EmailSenderAction".
- As I see, when the user who updates the record is a specific one, the email is sent adding the sender to the recipient, that is, the email address from which the email is coming, is added to the recipients together with the other emails from the list set by the flow.
  Clarification: the flow is not assigning the mail from the sender to the recipient, I already debugged it.

I guess it's a specific user setting. Any hint or help will help me!

Answer (score 1):

I found the cause, I don't quite understand why, but there is a difference between using templateName or using subject/body in the Apex action of the flow.

[image: Salesforce Flow]

When you use templateName, Salesforce adds the user who is executing the action as the recipient (for example, if the flow runs after a field update, the email of the person who is updating the field is added). This does not happen when using subject/body, which is another way to insert the information of the mail to be sent.

I didn't find an official documentation for this, but I came to that conclusion after my hours of testing. If anyone has official references, I'd be grateful!

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if it's because of the user's auto bcc setting.

It's found in the user's email settings - Click on your avatar, then Settings, and then in the menu on the left find My Email Settings.

When auto bcc is on, the email composer adds the user's email in the bcc line - maybe it does the same when they trigger an email to be sent via flow.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried that, but I kept getting the same result with mailings from the flow.